# php+mvc как можно передать title из представления в шаблон?

Tags: php, yii2, mvc

Пытаюсь разбираться с `PHP` и в частности с моделью `MVC`. Подскажите, пожалуйста:
Разбирая базовый набор фреймворка `yii2`, нашел, что в представлении `about.php` указывается `title` страницы, а дальше собственно html-код.

```
<?php
// ...
$this->title = 'About';
?>
<div class="site-about">
...
</div>
```

Как именно такое реализовано, ведь сначала загружается шаблон, а в нем уже выводится контент? Я понимаю, что есть класс `View`, который наполняется данными, и затем они выводятся. Но как в поля класса попадает код из представления? `about.php`, получается, как-то парсится, сохраняются значения полей класса, а сам html представления попадает в некую переменную `$content`, которая вызывается в шаблоне?

У меня получается так:

1. в модели я получаю `title` и пр. Либо из БД, либо прямо руками пишу там.
2. Контроллер вызывает шаблон, в котором использую полученные данные.
3. В середине шаблона включаю само представление посредством `include view.php`

Естественно, тут уже никак не передать title из представления. Нужно ли вообще иметь такую возможность, почему бы и не оставлять все данные в модели...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При чем тут передать из представления в шаблон? Во вьюхе переменная $this является объектом класса View. Этот объект передается во вьюху на уровне родительского контроллера (если не ошибаюсь) и во вьюхе свойству title, объекта View присваивается значение. Скинули объект во вьюху, изменили его там малость, а данные этого свойства вывели в шаблоне, потому что этот объект туда тоже передается.
Объект передан по ссылке, возможно поэтому некоторая путаница возникла.

Comment: Да, вопрос у меня тупой конечно, из-за недостатка знаний видать возник. Был не в курсе, что есть функции перехвата потока... Можете подсказать, правильно ли я понимаю, что грубый принцип "подключения" вьюшки  такой: `ob_start(); include('about.php'); $content = ob_get_contents(); ob_end_clean();`?

Comment: Вопрос не тупой, обычный. Вьюшка подключается приблизительно так. Можно заглянуть в класс View, там есть метод render(), который заведует подключением вьюшек.

Comment: Спасибо большое)